# How to reset Dlink dwr 710[Forgot Username and Password]

Tags: reset

I have set a username and password for my dwr710 but have forgotten them and I cant access router settings!
Any way to reset it?

Answer (score 2):

Just Open the device and you will find a hole next to the Green Light.
Just Put needle in that hole and press and hold for 10seconds in ON state. After that device will automatically reboot and then you can proceed to Use it. Username: admin Password is blank.

Try this in case you forgot admin password or by mistake you Disabled the HTTP Mode.

Answer (score 0):

There should either be a button to reset or a tiny hole with the button at the end which you can reach with a pin or needle. Try taking the outer shell off if there's none on the surface.

Answer (score -1):

There is a hole after the two green lights. Put an object that fits in it and press the button for about 10 seconds. Do this process when the dongle is connected to an electrical device or electric port. The dongle will automatically reset. It will show red light first.

Comment: This seems to add nothing over the existing answers.